# Underfull \hbox with minipage in tabularx environment

Tags: tabularx, itemize, minipage

I have the following MWE LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newenvironment{tablepage}[1][\linewidth]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}
        \begin{itemize}
}{\end{itemize}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \small
    \caption[Smart city goals, challenges and domains.]{Smart city goals, challenges and domains.}
    \label{tab:smart_domains}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Goals} & \textbf{Challenges} & \textbf{Domains} \\
        \toprule
        Economic growth &
            \begin{tablepage}
                \item Controlled transition of the labour market due to automation
            \end{tablepage} &
            \begin{tablepage}
                \item Smart Mobility
            \end{tablepage} \\
        \midrule
        Quality of life &
            \begin{tablepage}
                \item Winning the war on talent between metropolitan areas
            \end{tablepage} &
            \begin{tablepage}
                \item Smart Safety
            \end{tablepage} \\
        \midrule
        Reduced ecological footprint &
            \begin{tablepage}
                \item Social cohesion, inclusiveness, solidarity
                \item Secure digital environment, privacy
                \item Resilience
            \end{tablepage} &
            \begin{tablepage}
                \item Smart Energy, Water \& Waste
                \item Smart Buildings \& Living
                \item Smart Health
                \item Smart Education
                \item Smart Finance
                \item Smart Tourism \& Leisure
                \item Smart Retail \& Logistics
                \item Smart Manufacturing \& Construction
                \item Smart Government
            \end{tablepage} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When I compile it I get a number of `Underfull \hbox` warnings:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 6542) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 3039) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 1038) in paragraph
```

I have no idea what's causing them. Could anyone please advise?

Comment: they are not errors but warnings telling you that justifying text in narrow columns is hard and tex is having to over-stretch the inter word space. Often it is better to set table columns ragged right

Comment: Yes, fixed that thanks. I tried \raggedright in the column-spec but I'm still getting the warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose this code, defining a  new column type, based on `X`, which enters and leaves an itemize environment.  I added  loading of  `caption` to  have a decent spacing between caption and table, `ragged2e` and `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{enumitem}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother

    \newcolumntype{I}{>{\compress\itemize}X <{\enditemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \small
    \caption[Smart city goals, challenges and domains.]{Smart city goals, challenges and domains.}
    \label{tab:smart_domains}
    \setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, nosep, leftmargin= *, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X *{2}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}I}}
        \toprule
 \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Goals} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Challenges} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Domains} \\
 \toprule
        Economic growth &
                \item Controlled transition of the labour market due to automation
                 & \item Smart Mobility \\
        \midrule
        Quality of life & \item Winning the war on talent between metropolitan areas & \item Smart Safety \\
        \midrule
        Reduced ecological footprint &
                \item Social cohesion, inclusiveness, solidarity
                \item Secure digital environment, privacy
                \item Resilience &
                \item Smart Energy, Water \& Waste
                \item Smart Buildings \& Living
                \item Smart Health
                \item Smart Education
                \item Smart Finance
                \item Smart Tourism \& Leisure
                \item Smart Retail \& Logistics
                \item Smart Manufacturing \& Construction
                \item Smart Government \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What does `@minipagetrue` do?

Comment: An itemize environment at the beginning of a minipage inserts no vertical space. I stole the code somewhere on this site :o)

Comment: @Mico: You're right. I just had in mind the cells contents in the first column were  one-lined, so I didn't care about this point. I'll make some tests and post the modifications. However, note columns 2 and 3 are justified *if possible* since I use `\RaggedRight`.

Comment: @Mico: Done, mylord! ;o)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an adaptation of your code which (a) uses ragged-right by default in columns of type `X` and (b) employs an itemize-like list environment that maximizes the available space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % modified 'X' col. type

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet,wide=0pt,leftmargin=*}

\newenvironment{tablepage}[1][\linewidth]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}\begin{mylist}}{%
    \end{mylist}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\small
\caption[Smart city goals, challenges and domains.]%
        {Smart city goals, challenges and domains.}
\label{tab:smart_domains}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}LLL@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Goals} & \textbf{Challenges} & \textbf{Domains} \\
\midrule
Economic growth &
\begin{tablepage}
      \item Controlled transition of the labour market due to automation
\end{tablepage} &
\begin{tablepage}
      \item Smart Mobility
\end{tablepage} \\
\midrule
Quality of life &
\begin{tablepage}
      \item Winning the war on talent between metropolitan areas
\end{tablepage} &
\begin{tablepage}
      \item Smart Safety
\end{tablepage} \\
\midrule
Reduced ecological footprint &
\begin{tablepage}
      \item Social cohesion, inclusiveness, solidarity
      \item Secure digital environment, privacy
      \item Resilience
\end{tablepage} &
\begin{tablepage}
      \item Smart Energy, Water~\& Waste
      \item Smart Buildings~\& Living
      \item Smart Health
      \item Smart Education
      \item Smart Finance
      \item Smart Tourism~\& Leisure
      \item Smart Retail~\& Logistics
      \item Smart Manufacturing~\& Construction
      \item Smart Government
\end{tablepage} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Both yours and @Bernard's answers are correct but since I can only choose one I chose his as I find it more elegant.